# Comparison of 2 identical strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am going crazy - these 2 strings are identical but the code comes back as them being different!:

```
NSLog(@"nearbyAirport %@", nearbyAirport.geocode);
NSLog(@"airportToFind %@", airportToFind.geocode);

//Try and match geocodes.  If they are the same then airport is valid
if ([[airportToFind geocode] isEqualToString:[nearbyAirport geocode]])
{
return YES;
}

2010-10-29 15:10:59.808 Name[10658:207] nearbyAirport 6296598
2010-10-29 15:11:00.235 Name[10658:207] airportToFind 6296598
```

Comment: Have you checked for trailing spaces?  In the NSLog, put some chars after the %@.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that wouldn't work. Since they're numbers, maybe try and convert the string to integers and compare those two?

```
if ([[airportToFind geocode] intValue] == [[nearbyAirport geocode] intValue]) {
     return YES;
     NSLog(@"Success!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes around the strings themselves to make sure there aren't spaces.  I don't know anything about geocodes, are they always a number?  Could you convert them to NSNumber and do an integer compare?

Comment: +1 adding quotes around the strings in NSLog is a great debugging tactic to remember

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of `[airportToFind geocode]`?

Does it implement `isEqualToString:`?

Comment: Great catch... is it actually a NSString.